# Identify horror trilogy from 80s... third book was about zombies

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

Not much to go on, sorry.

I read them as a teen in the early/mid 80s.

The main character was a male, could have been an investigator or supernatural expert or hunter of some sort, and gets called in to deal with the current problem. He doesn't have any type of powers himself, IIRC, just a regular guy who has a knack for solving these sorts of things. His name (or the author's name?) may be Abraham (I think).

three books, the first (I think) was on vampires, the third was definitely on zombies. Can't remember what the second was about.

Comment: Good luck, and check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to help jog your memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Bloodscreams](https://www.goodreads.com/series/92895-bloodscreams)* by Robert W. Walker seems like a possible match. Book 1, *[Vampire Dreams](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8778563-vampire-dreams)*:

> Abraham Stroud is many things: archeologist, psychic, and detective. But more than that, he's a man who sees past the deceptive reality of everyday life, into the dark shadows where the horrors of myth and nightmare dwell. His is a lonely battle against monsters no one else dares to believe in.
>
> But you don't have to believe in vampires for them to tear you apart...

Book 3, *[Zombie Eyes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8554888-zombie-eyes)*:

> It starts with a sacred crypt, dug centuries ago, discovered under Manhattan. Buried with it is a diabolical creature spreading a strange contagion, claiming its victims by the thousands. But the dead aren't staying dead for long... and only one man is qualified to brave the unstoppable zombie army.
>
> ...IN A CITY OF THE DAMNED
>
> Psychic detective Abraham Stroud knows the origin of what festers in the unholy pit. And only he can battle the primeval horror as it prepares mankind for the ultimate sacrifice.

Just for the sake of completeness, the second book, *[Werewolf's Grief](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8231491-werewolf-s-grief)* seems to be about werewolves, there's a short story involving Abraham in *[Party of 8: The 1 That Got Away](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19164708-party-of-8)*, and a 5th book was released in 2015, *[The SubterraneanS](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25540669-the-subterraneans)*

What is linked above are the 2010 re-rereleases, but the books were originally published under the pen name of Geoffrey Caine in the 1990s as *[Curse of the Vampire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3199399-curse-of-the-vampire)*, *[Wake of the Werewolf](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1397938.Wake_Of_The_Werewolf)*, and *[Legion of the Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2423132.Legion_of_the_Dead)*.

Comment: THAT'S IT!!! Been wracking my brain forever to remember that series.

Thanks, mate!

Comment: As for the late publishing date, I think it's a re-publish under different titles (ie. those are definitely not the titles that come to mind). But it is definitely Abraham Stroud and the book description for the vampire and zombie ones are spot on.

Comment: ^_^ And the blurbs definitely sound like 80s pulp...

Comment: Now that I have the character's name, I found the books under their original titles (the ones I read them as in the 80s).

The vampire book was originally titled "Curse of the Vampire"
The werewolf book, "Wake of the Werewolf", and
the zombie book was "Legion of the Dead"

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=abraham+stroud&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlley-v-jSAhXJTbwKHeXeCaEQ7AkIRQ&biw=1366&bih=622

Comment: Ah. https://www.fictfact.com/series/3444/abraham-stroud-writing-as-geoffrey-caine?

Comment: Wait... Is Geoffrey Caine the same author and went under a different pseudonym when re-published under different titles?

Comment: It looks like that was the case. Oh, and there's a Fifth book too! *The SubterraneanS*

Comment: The fourth book is titled "Bayou Wulf", a sequel to the second book, and the sixth book is titled "Random Violence"... time for an afternoon or two to re-read the first trilogy and finish off the until-now unknown second trilogy... Off I go to Amazon!